# Added scroll to top when changing routes feature in angular2 but while unit-testing, it shows an error "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

This is the code for app.component.ts :-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromRoot from './reducers';
import {Router, NavigationEnd} from "@angular/router";


@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
constructor (
    private store: Store<fromRoot.State> ,
    private router: Router
) {
router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        if (val instanceof NavigationEnd){
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        }
    });
}
```

The unit testing code in app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { RouterOutletStubComponent , RouterStub } from '../testing';

describe('App: Hello', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            StoreModule.provideStore({}),
            RouterTestingModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule
        ],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            RouterOutletStubComponent
        ],
        providers: [
            { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }
            ]
    });
});

it('should create the app', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
}));
});
```

The error says:-

Failed: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

at new AppComponent (webpack:/Users/apple/Desktop/untitled%20folder/Website/hello-app/src/app/app.component.ts:18:18 <- src/test.ts:43455:22)

When I run the app by ng-serve, Application runs fine , while unit-testing is showing some errors. I googled a lot about this issue but couldn't find a solution. Moreover help me out with the issue that app doesn't scroll to top when changing routes. Thanks in advance.